# "Reverse" SSH to Raspberry Pi with mobile internet access

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi, remote, ip-address

I have a Raspberry Pi, which can access internet via mobile provider. I can install any software on this Pi and can program it to connect to any external host.

But it has no static IP.

Can I make this Pi to connect to some external host and then access Pi's command line from this host in "reverse direction"? What is the name of this technology and what software should I use?

Comment: This is not really Unix related, so I'm answering in a comment: you are looking for a dynamic DNS service, which keeps updating it's record to point to your Raspi's WAN IP. There are several providers (NoIP, DynDNS...).

Comment: However, you mention a mobile connection - if that means your Raspi is behind CGNAT, it won't work this way.

Comment: @Panki suppose my Pi is connected to some `host1`. Simultaneously I am also connected to `host1`. We both connected to `host1`. Can't we communicate?

Comment: Yeah, the answer by Blob describes that scenario

Answer (score 2):

At our company we provide a way for the computers we sell to our clients to "phone home" and make themselves available, though we have no idea what IP addresses they will wind up on.  When the service is started on their machine, it makes a connection to our always-on static IP web server machine:

ssh -R 2222:localhost:22 account@our.web.server

After the customer does this, we can log on to our web server and run

ssh -p 2222 account@localhost

This makes an SSH connection to port 2222 on the web server, which is forwarded to port 22 of the  client's machine, so we are logging into their machine via ssh.

Comment: Ah, looks workable!

Answer (score 0):

What you're essentially asking is "how can I build something that presents the Pi under a reliable address and allows remote connections".

Bad news first: most mobile providers do not allow for connecting to listening TCP ports on their subscriber's IP addresses. That rules out the "usual" dyndns solution, which could point a domainame to a changing IP address. (matter of fact, you might not even have a public IP address if you're on mobile, carrier-grade NAT and everything.)

So, you'll need your Pi to automatically connect to a virtual network where these things are possible – you're literally in need of a VPN.

Easiest is probably using one of the free-tier cloud hosting services (e.g. Oracle Cloud has pretty beefy free virtual machines, not that you need anything beefy), setting up a Linux in that, and setting up a [Wireguard](https://www.wireguard.com/) endpoint with NAT on it. You can then forward any port of the VM to the (VPN-intenral) IP address of the Pi over that network, and wireguard is very resilient against changing IP addresses, drop-y connections, so that's a pretty stable solution. I did use it for in-the-field sensors.

Also, if you want, you could also add the machines that are supposed to connect to the Pi to the same wireguard network. That way, they can directly connect to the private IP address, no need for public ports.

Nice thing is that wireguard is part of modern Linux kernels, so you literally only have to install a very small tool to set up keys and the connection; the rest, Linux can do out of the box.

There's very many guides on how to set up a Wireguard VPN VM, I quickly found [this azure-centric guide](https://joshspicer.com/wireguard-azure), haven't checked it too closely..

Comment: I have no affiliation, but if you can get a cloud VM (with a static IP), I'd personally use [rathole](https://github.com/rapiz1/rathole/) to allow access to SSH. It is what I use to make the SSH port on a local server public (I use a Digital Ocean droplet, but any other cloud VM would do). I don't have any affiliation to either, but I've used them and it is pretty simple

Comment: @cocomac a reverse SSH tunnel would serve the same purpose, no? See the other answer